# Can't mount an ISO

Tags: 12.04, mount, iso

Can't mount an ISO and the one time it did, it showed up empty.

```
iso is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

dmesg | tail

```
[46824.033565] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[46824.033568] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[46824.033570] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[46825.227460] wlan0: authenticate with 7a:b6:86:6b:13:19
[46825.242375] wlan0: send auth to 7a:b6:86:6b:13:19 (try 1/3)
[46825.246638] wlan0: authenticated
[46825.258025] wlan0: associate with 7a:b6:86:6b:13:19 (try 1/3)
[46825.260895] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 7a:b6:86:6b:13:19 (capab=0x1 status=0 aid=1)
[46825.260979] wlan0: associated
[46986.166953] ISOFS: Unable to identify CD-ROM format.
```

Using 12.04.2 64-bit

If you need any other system information, just ask.

Comment: Show us the commands you used leading up to this and is it just this ISO file or have you tried and failed with more?

Comment: What type of media are you trying to mount from your cdrom? ISO?

Answer (score 1):

[ISO 9660 Wikipedia's page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660)

The ISO 13490 standard is an extension to the ISO 9660 format that adds support for multiple sessions on a disc. Since ISO 9660 is by design a read-only, pre-mastered file system, all the data has to be written in one go or "session" to the medium. Once written, there is no provision for altering the stored content. ISO 13490 was created to allow adding more files to a writeable disc such as CD-R in multiple sessions.

**The conclusion:**
ISO9660 is a read-only filesystem. It can't be mounted in `rw` mode because there is no support for that in the filesystem itself.

Answer (score -1):

I believe I figured it, the ISO is not in 9660 format so I'm using iat to convert it

Comment: Yes, it is in iso9660 format...